# localtime() giving same output for different input timeticks

Tags: c

Can someone help to understand this. Why localtime gives the same output for different timeticks?.

```
       #include<stdio.h>

       #include<time.h>
       int main() 
       {
       int first = time(NULL);
       printf("%d\n", first);

       int second = first + 6;
        printf("%d\n", second);

       time_t loc_time = first;
       struct tm *starttime = localtime(&loc_time);

       time_t loc_time_end = second;

       struct tm *endtime  = localtime(&loc_time_end);

       printf("=====> start time is %d-%d-%d %02d:%02d:%02d", starttime->tm_mday, 1+starttime->tm_mon, starttime->tm_year+1900, starttime->tm_hour, starttime->tm_min, starttime->tm_sec); 
       printf("=====> end time is %d-%d-%d %02d:%02d:%02d", endtime->tm_mday, 1+endtime->tm_mon, endtime->tm_year+1900, endtime->tm_hour, endtime->tm_min, endtime->tm_sec); 

       }
```

Output:-1515384712
1515384718
=====> start time is 8-1-2018 04:11:58=====> end time is 8-1-2018 04:11:58

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `localtime` returns a pointer to *shared* structure

Comment: Iirc, Both calls return a pointer to the same underlying storage, which gets overwritten everytime you call local time.

Comment: How Can I solve it ?

Comment: @PraffullaPandey read [memcpy](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm)

Comment: No need for memcpy. Just the = operator.

Comment: `struct tm *starttime = localtime(&loc_time);` --> `struct tm starttime = *localtime(&loc_time);`

Comment: thanx. it worked!
But why this function (localtime) behaves like that ? what are the associated advantages?